# List item bullets overlapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an unordered list who's list items I would like displayed as two rows with multiple columns.

The problem is that the bullet of each list item is overlapping the previous list item.

How do I stop this from happening? I've figured out a messy solution adjusting the margins, but was wondering if there's an elegant fix for this?

**I would like to keep the bullets.**

**I do NOT want text within the list item to wrap around the bullet.**

I'm currently doing it like this:

```css
body > ul {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
body > ul > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}
body > ul > li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #23a;
}
body > ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #49b;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4L67/55/

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the CSS [***`list-style-position`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) property.

This property allows you to control whether the marker is outside the box, or inside.

The initial value is `outside`.

*From the spec:*

> [**12.5
>   Lists**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position)
>
> ***`list-style-position`***
>
> `outside`
>
> The marker box is outside the principal block box.
>
> `inside`
>
> The marker box is placed as the first inline box in the
>   principal block box, before the element's content and before any
>   `:before` pseudo-elements.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }          /* NEW */

body > ul {
    background: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body > ul > li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
    list-style-position: inside;       /* NEW */
    text-indent: -1em;                 /* NEW */
    padding-left: 1em;                 /* NEW */

}

body > ul > li:nth-child(even) {
    background: aqua;
}

body > ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
    <li></li>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</li>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified this: I do not want any text in the list item to wrap around the bullet. I'll edit my question. The only fix I found for this was wrapping <span> around the text and changing the display & margins. I was hoping I was missing something, that there's a more elegant fix. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `text-indent` and `padding-left` properties to prevent text from wrapping around the bullet. Answer revised.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  columns:3;
  column-gap:0;
}
body > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried with "columns", perhaps it can give you some help.

Comment: @jiandan I would like to keep the bullets. I'll edit my question.