# How to properly indent list items

Tags: html, css

Am using list items for my footer section and the address is slightly big so I put a break tag in order to have it properly formatted.

However, as you can see if you run my snippet, the text from the new line does not align with the text on top.

How can I make the text to never stay under the icon but be properly inline to the one on top?

```css
li:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  content: '\f192';
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #cc3333;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.contact_details li:last-child:before {
  content: '\f041' !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  display: inline-block;
  color: #cc3333;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-indent: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="contact_details">
  <li>+27 (0) 11 555 3333</li>
  <li>
    <a href="mailto:info@myemail.co.za">
  info@myemail.co.za</a>
  </li>
  <li>12 Address Hojaile City, Switzerland, <br>0169</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Negative margin-left on the pseudo elements, offset by a padding-left on the list items ... or absolute positioning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825241/3597276

Comment: Or a positive margin-left on the list items and a negative text-indent for the icons. Or float the icons to the left.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `display:flex;`? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4w2cbeb7/1/) it is,

```
li{
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  line-height:2em;
}
```

**Result;**

[image]

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `span` and use of `margin-left:(40 + 10)=50px`:

Html:

```
 <li>12 Address Hojaile City, Switzerland, <br><span>0169</span></li>
```

Css:

```
span {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
li:before {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    content: '\f192';
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #cc3333;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

ul.contact_details li:last-child:before {
    content: '\f041' !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    display: inline-block;
    color: #cc3333;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

span {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="contact_details">
  <li>+27 (0) 11 555 3333</li>
  <li>
  <a href="mailto:info@myemail.co.za">
  info@myemail.co.za</a>
  </li>
  <li>12 Address Hojaile City, Switzerland, <br><span>0169</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `div` with `class="box"`

```css
li:before {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    content: '\f192';
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #cc3333;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.contact_details li:last-child:before {
    content: '\f041' !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

ul.contact_details li:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    display: inline-block;
    color: #cc3333;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

div.box { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="contact_details">
  <li>+27 (0) 11 555 3333</li>
  <li>
    <a href="mailto:info@myemail.co.za">
    info@myemail.co.za</a>
  </li>
  <li><div class="box">12 Address Hojaile City, Switzerland, <br>0169</div></li>
</ul>
```